# iPhone json library to map the json to my own objects

Tags: ios, json, ios4

I seek a iPhone json library that parse json strings into Custom Objects (such as Employee, Course, etc, not into NSDictionary or NSArray)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think one exists. How would you design a general one, without knowing in advance about the kinds of objects that you'll need to parse into? And more critically, JSON is only designed to encode basic data types; it is not intended to be a full object serialization framework (those are usually language specific or have language-specific bindings). However, it should be very easy to write a converter to your custom objects.

Comment: `However, it should be very easy to write a converter to your custom objects.` using introspection you mean?

Comment: Depends a little bit on the structure of your JSON and of your custom objects -- knowing nothing else, it's hard to design it for you. But it could easily be straightforwardly declarative...an NSClassFromString, and a few setValue:forKeys. You'll have to provide more details in your question if you want more guidance.